# How to actually compute join of two subgroups of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I understand that join of two subgroups, say $\mathrm H$ and $\mathrm K$, of a group, say $\mathrm G$ is the intersection of all subgroups of $\mathrm G$ containing $\mathrm{HK=\{hk|h\in H, k\in K\}}$.

However, can someone explain how exactly do we compute $\mathrm{H \vee K}$, taking an example of some group like $\mathfrak S_3$ or $\mathbb Z_n$. I cannot grasp how the elements would differ in $\mathrm{H \vee K}$ from $\mathrm{HK}$.

Comment: **Note:** $H\vee K$ is always a subgroup but $HK$ might not be one (more precisely $HK$ is a subgroup iff $HK=KH$).

Comment: Are you saying I get $\mathrm{H \vee K}$ by $\mathrm{HK \cup KH}$?

Comment: No, I'm saying that $HK$ need not be a subgroup but $H\vee K$ is _by definition_ the intersection of all subgroups containing the set $HK$ which must be a subgroup since subgroups are closed under intersection.

Comment: For an example, consider $G = S_3$, and let $H = \langle(1\ 2)\rangle$ and $K = \langle(2\ 3)\rangle$. Then $|HK| = |H||K|/|H \cap K| = 4$, so by Lagrange's theorem, $HK$ cannot be a subgroup ($4$ does not divide $6$). In fact, the only divisor of $6$ that is $\geq 4$ is $6$ itself, so the only subgroup containing $HK$ is $S_3$, which means that $H \vee K = S_3$. Note that this indirect argument requires less grunge work than showing explicitly that every permutation in $S_3$ can be expressed as a product of $(1\ 2)$ and $(2\ 3)$.

Comment: @Bungo, I'm asking for a way to actually compute all the elements of $\mathrm{H \vee K}$ and see that it actually is the entire group $\mathrm S_3$.

Comment: @Tejas In general, that's exactly what you want to avoid, because it's a lot more grunge work. In the case of $S_3$ it's easy enough. $H \vee K$ contains $H$ and $K$, so it contains $(1\ 2)$ and $(2\ 3)$. Since $H \vee K$ is a subgroup, it must be closed under products, so it must contain $(1\ 2)(2\ 3) = (1\ 2\ 3)$ and $(2\ 3)(1\ 2) = (1\ 3\ 2)$, and it must contain $(1\ 2)(2\ 3)(1\ 2) = (1\ 3)$. And of course it must contain the identity. We have accounted for all elements of $S_3$, so $H \vee K = S_3$.

Comment: @Tejas Note that $HK$ contains $(1\ 2)$, $(2\ 3)$, $(1\ 2)(2\ 3) = (1\ 2\ 3)$, and the identity. It is missing $(1\ 3\ 2)$ and $(1\ 3)$, so it's not closed under multiplication and hence is not a subgroup. Similarly, $KH$ contains $(1\ 2)$, $(2\ 3)$, $(2\ 3)(1\ 2) = (1\ 3\ 2)$, and the identity. It is missing ($1\ 2\ 3)$ and $(1\ 3)$ and therefore is not a subgroup. Finally, note that $HK \cup KH$ contains everything except $(1\ 3)$ and so it's also not a subgroup.

Comment: When talking about computing subgroups, the answer always depends on how the subgroups are represented. If the subgroup is defined by generators, $H=\langle h_1,\ldots, h_n\rangle$, $K=\langle k_1,\ldots, k_m\rangle$ for example then $HK=\langle h_1,\ldots, h_n, k_1,\ldots, k_m\rangle$, but for general permutation groups the answer exists (see for example 'The Handbook of Computational Group Theory') but is far less easy to describe

Comment: @RobertChamberlain You mean $H\vee K$ instead of $HK$, right?

Comment: @DavidHill I don't seem to be able to correct it, but you are quite right, thank you